# Spaces because of xml formatting

Tags: xml, xslt, formatting

I get spaces in transformation output. And i believe it is because of xml formatting. How can i avoid it?

Xml source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl"?>
<index>
    <item value="golden ratio">
        <pages>
            <single value="574"></single>
        </pages>
    </item>
</index>
```

Xsl source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="index/item">
<xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="./pages"/>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="pages/*">
<xsl:value-of select="@value"/><br />
</xsl:template>
```

Result with unneeded spaces:
[image]

Comment: Well, you have not explained which result you want and why you do not simply process `<xsl:template match="/"><xsl:apply-templates select="index/item/pages/*"/></xsl:template>` from the beginning instead of relying on built-in templates.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Excuse me, i'm new to xml/xsl, i have some other stuff index/item which i need to process. I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Can you please still add the result you want? You could add `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>`, but that would result in `golden ratio574<br/>` which might not be what you want.

Comment: @DanielHaley very well! i will accept it as an answer.